# Getting Outlook/Exchange folder size info programmatically in a VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server, exchange-server-2003

I'm looking to create a VSTO that performs as a meter for my users so that they can see how much of their Exchange quota they are using at any given time.  The idea is that it will be in their toolbar and change from green (good) slowly to red (gotta delete stuff).

I have been searching most of the day online but have not seen any way to access the "Folder Size" and quota information in Outlook for an Exchange Store using C#.

Ideas are always welcome.

Regards,
Larry

FYI - my environment is currently running E2K3 with plans to upgrade over the next year.  If it's not possible with E2K3, please do not respond.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What version of exchange are you running? If you are running 2007 or later then you could use Exchange Web Services to get the information. Maybe this forum question will give you some ideas.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/31f9a157-4d19-44bf-ad58-62577915b624

Thanks
Niall

Comment: Thanks for the info.  We're currently on Exchange 2003, but will be migrating up over the next year.  I've seen some of this info before but it all pertains to E2K7 and higher.  I guess I'll just have to wait it out.  Kudos to you for responding, though.  Regards.

Comment: Hi Larry, Something that you can use in 2003 is webdav. This URL should give you some ideas. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320071

Comment: I'll have to take a lok at that.  Thanks.

Comment: The NTLM authentication is a bit of a blockade.  We have LM Compatibility set to the level where you're prompted.  We want the users to have transparency for this app only.